# Getting usernames from database that are not being used by a thread

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I have a multi threaded Java program where each thread gets one username for some processing which takes about 10 minutes or so.

Right now it's getting the usernames by a sql query that returns one username randomly and the problem is that the same username can be given to more than one thread at a time.

I don't want a username that is being processed by a thread, to be fetched again by another thread. What is a simple and easy way to achieve this goal?

Comment: Your question is way too vague.  Please provide data layouts, sample data, and what you would really like to do with the data.

Answer (score 1):

Step-by-step solution:

1. Create a threads table where you store the threads' state. Among other columns, you need to store the owner user's id there as well.
2. When a thread is associated to a user, create a record, storing the owner, along with all other juicy stuff.
3. When a thread is no longer associated to a user, set its owner to null.
4. When a thread finishes its job, remove its record.
5. When you randomize your user for threads, filter out all the users who are already associated to at least a thread. This way you know any users at the end of randomization are threadless.
6. Make sure everything is in place. If, while working on the feature some thread records were created and should be removed or disposed from its owner, then do so.

Comment: Handling of crashed threads, where the thread exits without removing its record, needs external management with this approach. It's also hard to get right if multiple threads must concurrently select a free user id; you'll want to lock the table for the actual fetching of a free user id.

Comment: (It's still more sensible than most of the suggestions given here).

Comment: You do not necessarily need to lock the table, you might want to use a task queue and handle thread start sequentially.

Comment: Also, you can ping threads and if no response is received, you can remove them. I did not dwelve in the details, since they depend on the core situation a lot

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of ways to do this... I can think of three solution to this problem:

1) A singleton class with a array that contains all the user already in use. Be sure that the acces to the array is synchronized and you remove the unused users from it.

2) A flag in the user table that contains a unique Id referencing the thread that is using it. After you have to manage when you remove the flag from the table.

-> As an alternative, why do you check if a pool of connections shared by all the thread could be the solution to your problem ?

Comment: do you happen to have a example of the singleton method? I've never used it and I did read some tutorials about it, but still unsure on how to use this for what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You could do one [batch query](http://www.javaranch.com/journal/200510/batching.html) that returns all of the usernames you want from the database and store them in a List (or some type of collection).

Then ensure synchronised access to this list to prevent two threads taking the same username at the same time. Use a synchronised list or a synchronised method to access the list and remove the username from the list.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to add another column to your users table.this column is a simple flag that shows if a user has an assigned thread or not.

but when you query the db you have to wrap it in a transaction.
you begin the transaction and then first you select a user that doesn't have a thread after that you update the flag column and then you commit or roll back.
since the queries are wrapped in a transaction the db handles all the issues that happen in scenarios like this.

with this solution there is no need to implement synchronization mechanisms in your code since the database will do it for you.

if you still have problems after doing this i think you have to configure isolation levels of your db server.

Comment: This will serialize all work, so that only one worker is doing anything useful and the others are waiting on a row lock in a database query. It's a common - but incorrect - "solution" to the queueing problem. Changing isolation levels will have no effect in this case.

Comment: why? It depends on how the database server handles locks, and transactions internally. if the db locks the whole table it may have some peeformance issues. and each transaction works on a different row. i thought configuring isolation levels is needed to not read uncommited data.

Comment: but yes it's not the correct solution to the queueing problem.

Comment: The question is about PostgreSQL. PostgreSQL will never read uncommitted data, and in fact it's not possible to do so from the SQL level. You can't do it even if you want to. Also, when you `UPDATE` a row the DBMS will lock that row until the transaction commits or rolls back. If another transaction tries to `UPDATE` the same row (or `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE/SHARE` it) it'll block until the first tx commits or rolls back. Your workers will queue up on a row lock, rendering your approach equivalent to just having a single worker. You need PostgreSQL 9.5's `SKIP LOCKED` to get around that.

Comment: sorry, i didn't see postgresql. but for the second part. the db will lock the row and other transactions that need the same row will be bloked until the lock owner finishes the transaction but in this case each transaction is selecting and updating diffrent users row.

Comment: ... and how would you ensure that each thread gets a different username? The whole problem the poster wants to solve is how to get a different username for each worker to process. You're relying on the problem being solved in order to solve the problem.

Comment: 1- each thread starts a transaction 2- get a random user like this or any other query(select * from user where has_an_assigned_thread_flag=false order by RANDOM() limit 1) 3- update that row's flag column to true (update users set has_an_assigned_thread_flag=true where id=returned_row_pk_id ) 4- commit or roll back. i think it solves the problem!

Comment: Well, if you're willing to `ORDER BY random()` then yes, that'll often work, but for nontrivial user-id counts that'll perform terribly, and also removes any opportunity to ensure work is processed in any kind of reasonable time sequence. It'll also devolve to the mostly-serialized case when there are few user IDs.

Comment: yes you said it first and i agreed with that. it's not a good solution for queueing but there is no detail in the question and it's too vague.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to want a work queue system. Don't reinvent the wheel - use a well established existing work queue.

Robust, reliable concurrent work queuing is unfortunately tricky with relational databases. Most "solutions" land up:

- Failing to cope with work items not being completed due to a worker restart or crash;
- Actually land up serializing all work on a lock, so all but one worker are just waiting; and/or
- Allowing a work item to be processed more than once

PostgreSQL 9.5's new `FOR UPDATE SKIP LOCKED` feature will make it easier to do what you want in the database. For now, use a canned reliable task/work/message queue engine.

If you must do this yourself, you'll want to have a table of active work items where you record the active process ID / thread ID of the worker that's processing a row. You will need a cleanup process that runs periodically, on thread crash, and on program startup that removes entries for failed jobs (where the worker process no longer exists) so they can be re-tried.

Note that unless the work the workers do is committed to the database in the same transaction that marks the work queue item as done, you will have timing issues where the work can be completed then the DB entry for it isn't marked as done, leading to work being repeated. To absolutely prevent that requires that you commit the work to the DB in the same transaction as the change that marks the work as done, or that you use two-phase commit and an external transaction manager.